A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: payload
I am a novice developer, please tell me why an error occurs when calling initPayment: "A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: payload. Value: [Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component]"
import { useSQLiteContext } from "expo-sqlite";
const paymentSlice = createSliceWithThunks({
  name: "payments",
  initialState,
  reducers: (create) => ({
    initPayment: create.asyncThunk(
      async function (_, { rejectWithValue }) {
        try {
          const db = useSQLiteContext();
          const payments = await db.getAllAsync<Payments>("SELECT * FROM payments");
          return payments;
        } catch (err) {
          return rejectWithValue(err);
        }
      },
      {
        fulfilled: (state, action: PayloadAction<Payments[]>) => {
          state.list = action.payload;
        },
        rejected: (state) => {
          console.error("Error");
        },
      }
    ),

  }),
});

export default function Main() {
  const { theme } = useContext(ThemeContext);

  return (
    <SQLiteProvider
      databaseName="payments.db"
      assetSource={{ assetId: require("../assets/payments.db") }}
    >
      <Provider store={store}>
            <NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
              <PaperProvider>
                <StatusBar style="auto" />
                <Stack.Navigator
                  screenOptions={{
                    contentStyle: {
                      backgroundColor: theme.colors.background,
                      padding: 20,
                    },
                    headerShadowVisible: false,
                    headerStyle: {
                      backgroundColor: theme.colors.background,
                    },
                  }}
                >
                  <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
                  <Stack.Screen name="Payment" component={Payment} />
                </Stack.Navigator>
              </PaperProvider>
            </NavigationContainer>
      </Provider>
    </SQLiteProvider>
  );
}


The non-serializable action payload error is fairly self-explanatory, and as for the hook usage error, you can't call useSQLiteContext in the paymentSlice thunk action creator. You can call useSQLiteContext in a React component or custom React hook. Is there any non-React-hook way of accessing your DB instance? Your post should be limited to one specific issue, so which of the two you've mentioned would you like to address in this post and which do you want to split out into its own post?

how to access a DB instance without using the React hook?

I don't think you can, since I don't see anything in the Expo-SQLite documentation other than this useSQLiteContext hook.

You cannot call React hooks from anything other than React functions and custom React hooks, so calling the useSQLiteContext in the initPayment action creator is invalid.
You can however call useSQLiteContext in the React component that is dispatching initPayment and pass the DB instance to the Thunk action.
Example:
const paymentSlice = createSliceWithThunks({
  name: "payments",
  initialState,
  reducers: (create) => ({
    initPayment: create.asyncThunk(
      async function ({ db }, { rejectWithValue }) {
        try {
          return db.getAllAsync<Payments>("SELECT * FROM payments");
        } catch (err) {
          return rejectWithValue(err);
        }
      },
      {
        fulfilled: (state, action: PayloadAction<Payments[]>) => {
          state.list = action.payload;
        },
        rejected: (state) => {
          console.error("Error");
        },
      }
    ),
  }),
});

import { useSQLiteContext } from "expo-sqlite";

...

const SomeComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const db = useSQLiteContext();

  ...

  const someHandler = async () => {
    ...
    const payments = await dispatch(initPayment({ db })).unwrap();
    ...
  };

  ...
};

Alternative to passing db to specific Thunk actions that use it
Create an intermediate wrapper component that can call useSQLiteContext hook and pass db in the Thunk middlware's extraArgument.
See getDefaultMiddleware API reference for details.
Example:
import { useSQLiteContext } from "expo-sqlite";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import rootReducer from "../path/to/rootReducer";

const Wrapper = ({ children }) => {
  const db = useSQLiteContext();

  // Create stable/memoized Redux store instance reference
  const store = useMemo(() => {
    return configureStore({
      reducer: rootReducer,
      middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
        getDefaultMiddleware({
          thunk: {
            extraArgument: {
              db, // <-- pass db to Thunk middleware
            }
          }
        }),
    });
  }, [db]);

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      {children}
    </Provider>
  );
};

Render Wrapper in Redux Provider component's place in Main.
export default function Main() {
  const { theme } = useContext(ThemeContext);

  return (
    <SQLiteProvider
      databaseName="payments.db"
      assetSource={{ assetId: require("../assets/payments.db") }}
    >
      <Wrapper>
        <NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
          <PaperProvider>
            <StatusBar style="auto" />
            <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ ... }}>
              <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
              <Stack.Screen name="Payment" component={Payment} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
          </PaperProvider>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </Wrapper>
    </SQLiteProvider>
  );
}

Access the extra ThunkApi property to get the passed db instance.
const paymentSlice = createSliceWithThunks({
  name: "payments",
  initialState,
  reducers: (create) => ({
    initPayment: create.asyncThunk(
      async function (_, { extra, rejectWithValue }) {
        try {
          const { db } = extra; // <-- access db from extraArgument
          return db.getAllAsync<Payments>("SELECT * FROM payments");
        } catch (err) {
          return rejectWithValue(err);
        }
      },
      {
        fulfilled: (state, action: PayloadAction<Payments[]>) => {
          state.list = action.payload;
        },
        rejected: (state) => {
          console.error("Error");
        },
      }
    ),
  }),
});


I don't want to transfer a database instance to each function, there are no options not to transfer an instance?

@Apeva I have another idea, but let me ask first, do you use the Redux store instance elsewhere in your code?

not yet,,,,,,,,

@Apeva Ok, well the other idea I had was to create a wrapper component that could use the useSQLiteContext hook and pass the db reference to the store's Thunk middleware's extraArgument property, then all the Thunks can access it. If this is something you are interested in seeing an example of let me know. The downside is that the Redux store would need to be created within the ReactTree and wouldn't be available outside it.

Yes, it is interesting, I will be very grateful

Ok @Apeva, I have updated my answer to include an alternative method.

@Apeva Has this sufficiently answered/addressed your question/issue?

I'll try, I'll let you know, thanks
